# How to successfully download the old version of lsmeans package

Tags: r, rstudio, cran, lsmeans, emmeans

I'd like to download version 2.26-3 of lsmeans package.

An error occurs when I try to download an old version of the lsmeans package. 
I've tried two options for downloading the old versions of lsmeans.

Option 1)

```
path<- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/lsmeans/lsmeans_2.26-3.tar.gz"
install.packages(path, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Option 2)

```
library(devtools)
 install_version("lsmeans", version = "2.26-3", dependencies=FALSE, repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/")
```

When I attempt either option, I am prompted to:

> "These packages have more recent versions available. which would you
>   like to update."

It then it lists a number of packages. I have attempted to choose both options "all" and "none"

The main error code I keep getting is this:

> Error: (converted from warning) unable to access index for repository
>   http://glmmadmb.r-forge.r-project.org/repos/bin/windows/contrib/3.5:
>
> cannot open URL
>   'http://glmmadmb.r-forge.r-project.org/repos/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES'

why does it direct me to this glmmadmb.r address which  no longer exists. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have other code that promotes warnings to errors? Any idea where the "http://glmmadmb.r-forge.r-project.org/" URL is coming from? You might have to install older versions of all of lsmean's dependencies yourself.

Comment: I do not know where the "glmmadmb.r-forge.r-project.org" was coming from, but the problem was solved by installing all the lsmeans dependencies individually. Thanks!

Comment: @SkipT Just checking. Is the current lsmeans falling short of what you need? I’ve tried to make it as supportive as possible of old versions and easy to transition. Objects from 2.26-3 and earlier can mess up the namespace if mixed with those from emmeans or the newest lsmeans.